# LINQ XML Get value of element from multiple where statement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

First question on SO, apologies if I mess some of this up. I'm new to c# and LINQ and have spent the past 2 days searching SO for a solution, none seem to be exactly what I'm after. So...

The xml file I'm querying is generated from a DICOM Structured Report file. I'm trying to get specific values of elements from this xml file. These elements correspond to specific measurements that were taken during an ultrasound examination. The entire xml file is 15k lines long so for simplicity I've edited it. I'll just show one example of what I'm trying to do but the process will be the same for all other elements I'm looking to get.

The element I want to get has to meet 3 criteria, in this case *Tricuspid Valve*, *Peak Velocity* and *Regurgitant Flow* but this changes depending on the measurement that was taken. Once those criteria are met I want to get the value of , which in this case is 2120.

The xml

```
<report type="Comprehensive SR">
   <document>
      <content>
         <container flag="SEPARATE">
          <container flag="SEPARATE">
               <code>
                  <meaning>Tricuspid Valve</meaning>
               </code>
               <container flag="SEPARATE">
                  <num>
                     <concept>
                        <meaning>Peak Velocity</meaning>
                     </concept>
                     <code>
                        <meaning>Regurgitant Flow</meaning>
                     </code>
                     <value>2120</value>
                     <unit>
                        <value>mm/s</value>
                     </unit>
                  </num>
```

My code in c#

```
XDocument xmlSR = XDocument.Load("DICOMSRtest.xml");
var TRVmax = from c in xmlSR.Descendants("container")
        where (string)c.Element("code").Element("meaning") == "Tricuspid Valve"
        where (string)c.Element("concept").Element("meaning") == "Peak Velocity"
        where (string)c.Element("code").Element("meaning") == "Regurgitant Flow"
        select c.Element("container").Element("num").Element("value");

        Console.Write("TRVmax: " + TRVmax);
```

When I run the code I get the following

```
TRVmax: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Xml.Linq.XElement]
```

Any help or direction to some documentation which I can read to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you get is an enumerator that has not been executed yet - LINQ expressions are evaluated lazily. You have to iterate over the enumerator or convert it to a container type (e.g. `ToList`) to get the _result_ of the expression.

Comment: As @MrBeanBremen pointed out, try changing the console write to `Console.Write("TRVmax: " + TRVmax.ToArray());` or `Console.Write("TRVmax: " + TRVmax.Count());`

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");

            List<XElement> xContainers = doc.Descendants("container").Where(x => x.Element("num") != null).ToList();

            List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();
            foreach (XElement xContainer in xContainers)
            {
                Container newContainer = new Container();
                containers.Add(newContainer);
                newContainer.code = (string)xContainer.Descendants("code").FirstOrDefault();
                newContainer.concept = (string)xContainer.Descendants("concept").FirstOrDefault();
                newContainer.value = (int)xContainer.Descendants("value").FirstOrDefault();
                newContainer.unit = (string)xContainer.Descendants("unit").FirstOrDefault();
            }


        }
    }
    public class Container
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string concept { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }
}
```